# How to print the results of an input variable inside a function

Tags: function, input, printing, scope

here is my code, the input variable is map1 where the user is promoted to enter a filepath, I want to `print('map saved to', map1)` after the user inputs the location, but I am getting the error `NameError: name 'map1' is not defined`. The variable is defined and is assigned a value when the user puts an input. Why won't it print?

```
def question2(two):
     map1 = input('where do you want to save the map? please enter filepath with image type e.g C:/map.jpg: ')
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,12))
     filtered_buildings.plot(ax = ax, color = 'red', edgecolor = 'black',)
     Highway.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black')
     Tunnel.plot(ax = ax, color = 'green', alpha = 0.5, edgecolor = 'black',)
     Tunnel_buffer.plot(ax = ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor = 'black',)
     ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
     plt.title('Filtered Buildings') 
     plt.savefig(fname=map1, dpi=300)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_again = 'start_string'
    while not do_again in ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'No', 'n', 'no']:
        do_again = input("Would you like to save the final map? (y/n)? ").lower()
    if do_again == 'yes' or do_again == 'y' or do_again == 'Yes':
        print('Saving Map...')
        print('map saved to', map1)
        question2()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statements

```
print('Saving Map...')
print('map saved to', map1)
```

Should be directly after the `plt.savefig(fname=map1, dpi=300)` and before `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Correct code is:

```
def question2():
     map1 = input('where do you want to save the map? please enter filepath with image type e.g C:/map.jpg: ')
     fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,12))
     filtered_buildings.plot(ax = ax, color = 'red', edgecolor = 'black',)
     Highway.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black')
     Tunnel.plot(ax = ax, color = 'green', alpha = 0.5, edgecolor = 'black',)
     Tunnel_buffer.plot(ax = ax, facecolor='none', edgecolor = 'black',)
     ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
     plt.title('Filtered Buildings') 
     plt.savefig(fname=map1, dpi=300)
     print('Saving Map...')
     print('map saved to', map1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_again = 'start_string'
    while not do_again in ['yes', 'y', 'Yes', 'No', 'n', 'no']:
        do_again = input("Would you like to save the final map? (y/n)? ").lower()
    if do_again == 'yes' or do_again == 'y' or do_again == 'Yes':
        question2()
```